# MySQL multiple statement blocks

Tags: mysql, deadlock

As we know, MySQL supports *Multiple Statement Queries*, i.e., we can execute two or more statements separated by a semicolon with only one function call. This can be done using, for example, the PHP function `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Now I have a question. I want to execute the following two statements in one call, but the call does not return for a very long time. I wonder whether these two statements will cause *dead blocks*.

If so, how should I resolve it?

```
update users set user_openid='' where user_openid='12345';
update users set user_openid='23456', user_fakeid='34567' where user_login='cifer';
```

Comment: have you tried running these commands back to back one at a time or from a shell command? That will show if it may be one of the queries that is the culprit.

Comment: Are user_openid and user_login fields both indexed?  It could be the lookup for one (or both) of them is taking a long time.

Comment: @amaster507 thanks for remanding, I almost forget the mysql shell, I tried it, there is no dead block issue. It's other part of my code that cause the long time returning...